# How to read odd rows if column is odd and sum these values in R

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns

I'm trying to calculate the `sum` column wise of the cells in an 8x8 matrix `M[[K]]` for when the column is odd it adds the odd rows under it; if the column is even it add the even row cells under it. I then need this to loop through a data folder.

```
 vin <- rep(c(1,0),(NoParticipants/2)) 
 vout <- rep(c(0,1),(NoParticipants/2)) 
 M <- vector("list") 
 total <- vector("list") 
 group <- vector("list") 

 for(k in 1:NoGames){ 
   M[[k]] <- (CumulativeAdjacencyMatrices[[k]][[20]]) 
   total[[k]] <- colSums(M[[k]]) 
   group[[k]] <- (M[[k]]%*%vin)*vin + (NoRounds - (M[[k]]%*%vin))*vout 
 }
```

The line with `group[[k]]` is giving back negative integers (which it shouldn't). How can I re-write the command to do what I want it to? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative to your approach as just traversing through odd and even indexes as follows :

```
#sample matrix
m <- matrix(sample.int(20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]   11    9    2   14   10   11    9    2
 [2,]   17    6    9    7    4   17    6    9
 [3,]    1   10   20   12   18    1   10   20
 [4,]    1   14    8    3   12    1   14    8
 [5,]   14   10   11    9    2   14   10   11
 [6,]    7    4   17    6    9    7    4   17
 [7,]   12   18    1   10   20   12   18    1
 [8,]    3   12    1   14    8    3   12    1

#adding odd index columns
> colSums(m[,seq(1,ncol(m),2)])
[1] 66 69 83 83

#adding even index columns
> colSums(m[,seq(2,ncol(m),2)])
[1] 83 75 66 69

# column 1 = sum rows 1,3,5,7 and so on...
for(i in 1:(ncol(m)-2)){
    m[,i] <- rowSums(m[,seq(i,8,2)])
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this does kind of help. How can I then incorporate the vin and vout binary functions? This would set it that every odd should use vin to make all evens null and vout will use all the evens while making all the odds null. For instance, I want column 1 to sum rows 1,3,5,7 to give 38 and the column 2 should count rows 2,4,6,8 to give 36 and so on??

Answer (score 0):

I found where I was wrong. I needed to replace NoRounds with total[[k]] in the last line.